# Keep stacked view on bottom

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

Hello im using a navigation drawer with the fragments replaced with frame but i want to keep a bottom space an change fragments in the white space. How can i do this?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

MainActivity.java

package panayiotis.mysmarthome;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;

import panayiotis.mysmarthome.fragments.Dashboard;
import panayiotis.mysmarthome.fragments.Home;
import panayiotis.mysmarthome.eventbus.MessageEvent;
import panayiotis.mysmarthome.libraries.mqtt.ImqttCallback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImqttCallback{

    //Defining Variables
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mPendingRunnable;

    private Fragment selectedFragment;

    private Snackbar snackbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        initInstances();
    }

    private void initInstances() {
        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (!menuItem.isChecked())
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                else {
                    //Closing drawer on item click
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }

                selectedFragment = null;

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.dashboard:
                        selectedFragment = new Dashboard();
                        break;
                    case R.id.home:
                        selectedFragment = new Home();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                }

                mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, selectedFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                };

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

                // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
                if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
                    mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
                    mPendingRunnable = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        selectedFragment = new Dashboard();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, selectedFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(drawerLayout, "Connecting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

        snackbar.show();
        MySmartHome.getInstance().getMqttClient().connect(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        MySmartHome.getInstance().getMqttClient().disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * Eventbus function
     */
    @Subscribe
    public void onEventBusReceived(MessageEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == MessageEvent.Type.LOG_OUT) {
            logout();
        }
    }

    private void logout() {
        MySmartHome.getInstance().getDataManager().deleteAllData();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    /**
     * ImqttCallback
     */
    @Override
    public void connected() {
        snackbar.dismiss();
        snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(drawerLayout, "Connected", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

        snackbar.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionFailed() {

    }
}
```

Comment: need some clarification .. do you need fixed blue color view regardless of fragment change.

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem yes

Comment: i have posted my answer.please look into it. If it worked ,please upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish this layout by background drawable and `paddingBottom`. like below.
layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_frame"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

bg_frame.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:height="70dp" android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: i also want to hide or show the view like a snagbar

Comment: Which view do you want to hide or show? R.id.frame ?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you issue. @SriMaharshi Manchem 's answer may be helps.

Comment: his answer has an issue if you can help

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a margin? layout_marginBottom=

Comment: no because the frame is replaced with the fragment of the navigation

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout.Your problem will be solved.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/fixedView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_above="@id/fixedView"
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{panayiotis.mysmarthome/panayiotis.mysmarthome.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: in this line  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

Comment: can you post build.gradle dependencies.make sure to use compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

Comment: Please use which i have posted.

Comment: i have to change the compiled version to 23

Comment: I think, issue is in binding the navigationitemlistener to the context.. can you post your activity class where nav item select listener is implemented.